# ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'NoneType'>, <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, keras

`x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test` are `numpy.ndarray` and their shapes are respectively `(712, 7),(179,7),(712,)` and `(179,)`

Keras functional API

```
i=Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1],))
x=Dense(32,activation='relu')(i)
x=Dense(64,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dense(128,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dense(2,activation='sigmoid')(x)

model=Model(i, x)
```

The input shape is set to (7,)
I keep getting this error while fitting

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'NoneType'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated